# cheese not working with latest update of gstreamer

Tags: 10.10, cheese

> One of more needed gstreamer elements are missing:
>   gconfaudiosrc,gconfvideosink.

According to the information I found both are part of the GStreamer Good Plugins 0.10 which Synaptic says I have installed.

I have cheese 2.32 on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: I solved it by doing:

Comment: sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-gconf

Comment: I'm adding your comment as an answer.  In the future, don't hesitate to answer your own questions, as it might help others find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by running `sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-gconf`